# Updating a variable value of a user object in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to implement some functionality that allows a user to edit their personal information in a Django project using Django forms. When a user enters the new value in the form and hits enter, they are brought back to the main profile page which is correct however, the values remain the same as before. Below is how I have tried to implement the functionality:

**Forms**

```
class UpdateProfile(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=False)
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    age = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    height = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    weight = forms.IntegerField(required=False)

    class Meta:
#Here are the fields that i want editable
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'height', 'weight')

#Here im trying to commit the changes to the user and return the user
    def save(self, commit=True):
        super(UpdateProfile, self).__init__(commit)


        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

**Views**

```
def update_profile(request):
    args = {}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateProfile(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('account/profile.html'))

    else:
        form = UpdateProfile()
        args['form'] = form
        return render(request, 'account/edit_profile.html', args)
```

**HTML**

```
% block head %}
    <title>Profile</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="container">
        <form method="POST" action="{% url 'account:profile' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <br>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your form is submitting directly to the view profile page. But that page is presumably not expecting to validate a form. You need to submit it back to the update_profile page, which you normally do by using an action of just `"."` in the form HTML element.

```
<form method="POST" action=".">
```

Once you've done that, you'll see some issues with your form `save()` method. That method does not do anything useful anyway; you should remove it and let the superclass one be called automatically.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer me. I took your advice and fixed the form HTML element. However even with your suggestions it continues to do the same as before. Is there anywhere else that I should be looking that might contain the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This line seems wrong:

```
super(UpdateProfile, self).__init__(commit)
```

You're calling `__init__` from the parent class, but the method being called is `save()`... Also you're refering to a `user` variable which is (hopefully) not defined in this scope.